# Awk: extract content within bcracket

Tags: regex, awk

What's a good way to extract foo.com from the string using awk?

```
ImaString (foo1.com, ,bar.com) (foo2.com, , bar.com)
```

Output i want: 
foo1.com
foo2.com

Comment: please provide what output you want to see

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one field in the comma separated lists:

```
awk -F, -v RS="[)(]" 'NF>1{print $1}' inputfile
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what im looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the snarky comment, but the question is not clearly worded.  You might try setting FS to the regex "(|," and let awk extract the field for you automatically:

```
$ awk -F ',|\\(' ...
```

Comment: Thank for your prompt response. Basically, i want to extract foo.com within the bracket and this foo.com and occur 2 or more times.

Comment: So you want to count the number of times "foo.com" appears as the first element of a comma separated list enclosed in parentheses?

Comment: That's right, but i do not want the count the number of times, i want to extract "foo.com" out as the first element of a comma separated list enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: Still not clear what you are after. Do you want to extract any string that appear as first element of the the bracket delimited, commas separated lists? Provide sample input and required output sample files for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Question is still a bit unclear, are you asking for this?

```
$ echo "ImaString (foo.com, ,bar.com) (foo.com, , bar.com)" | 
  awk -F '(' '{sub(/,.*/,"", $2);{print $2}}'
foo.com
```

Comment: Thanks, what is what exactly i want but foo.com is a variable so i want it to print as many times foo.com appear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use awk for this? Sed and grep would seem to be a better choice for this.

```
$ echo "ImaString (foo1.com, ,bar.com) (foo2.com, , bar.com)" | 
  grep -E -o '\(([a-zA-Z0-9]*\....),' | sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/,$//'
foo1.com
foo2.com
```

Dump the results into a bash variable, count them with wc, or stick them in a bash array.

Comment: I guess i wasn't clear enough on my first post. I have edited it. Basically foo.com could be foo1.com, foo2.com etc. I've edited the first post with the result i want to see.

Comment: @ Spencer Rathbun: awk is probably a better choice than using multiple processes with a pipe.

Comment: @ripat I'm curious as to your reasoning. Process spawning is deliberately cheap in linux/unix for just this purpose. You can break a problem into manageable pieces and apply the appropriate utility to each.

Comment: @ready I've edited the regex to allow for numbers in the captured section. You sure you want your results inline? One result per line is easier to pipe through `uniq -c` and get a count of each item.

Comment: @Spencer there is nothing wrong in piping multiple commands when what you want to do cannot be done with one or when you only have a few lines to process. Otherwise it's always better to avoid the pipes when you can. Also using `grep|awk` or `grep|sed` can give you the right to participate to [this contest](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#grep) ;=)

Comment: @ripat a touch, a veritable touch! I used grep because I couldn't get sed to output only the selection for some reason, but I would have preferred just sed. I can see your point, but I prefer to use computer cycles, rather than me cycles. I find it more obvious to see what is going on in a piped setup, and I don't really care if it takes a few seconds instead of a few milliseconds.